# Simple javascript code does not work. What is the mistake?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, alert, prompt

please tell what would be the correct way to write the code. If user gives ='1', i want $word='year', else - $word='years'.

Ty

Please find code below:

```
let word; 
let age= prompt('how old?',);
if (age='1') {word ='year';} 
else {word ='years';}
alert(`You are ${age} ${word} old!`);
```

If you give any number in prompt it always gives 1 year - no matter what other number you give. Want it to work correctly('2' - 'years', '3' - 'years', '1' - 'year')

Comment: Common mistake for beginners: `if (age='1')` should be `if (age=='1')`. `=` is for assignment, `==` (and `===`, which is often safer) are for comparison.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I'm surprised you didn't post that as an answer to claim your easy 10 points.

Comment: @user1538301 perhaps I should, but when it's so straightforward (and almost certainly has been asked loads of times on here before, although I confess I didn't try to find a specific duplicate) I didn't see the point. (There doesn't tend to be a lot of upvotes given for answers like that, I'm happy to let newer users claim what credit there is :) )

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```js
let word;
let age= prompt('how old?',);
if (age=='1') {word = 'year';} 
else {word = 'years';}
alert(`You are ${age} ${word} old!`);
```

Works now... the case was the equals are not correct...

Comment: You should use code snippets next time you post. I'm pretty sure that's the main reason your post was downvoted (also because this is a very common mistake that I'm sure has been answered before)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You are supposed to used comparison operators when checking if the age is equal to 1, the single = is an assigning operator so it makes age equal to 1.

```js
let word; 
let age= prompt('how old?',);
if (age=='1') {word ='year';} 
else {word ='years';}
alert(`You are ${age} ${word} old!`);
```